# Random font size and set a min and max of the character

Tags: javascript, font-size

I have a few problems here.

a)How to add random font size into this code?

b)How to set the limitation of min(3) and max(8) characters?

Javascript

```
function randomString(Length) {
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  for (var i = 0; i < Length; i++)
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  return text;
}
function ChangingRandomString(Length) {
  setInterval(function () {
    document.getElementById("random").innerHTML = randomString(Length);
  }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Adding Random Fond size**

```
document.getElementById("myP").style.fontSize = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 3)+"px";
```

you have to implement your own code to randomize it

**How to set the limitation of min(3) and max(8) characters?**

```
function randomString(Length)
{
   if(Length < 3) Length = 3;
    if(Length > 8) Length = 8;
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="myP">This is a paragraph.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Set font size</button>
 
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myP").style.fontSize = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 3)+"px";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This should do your job